# How to point my domain to a host whose ip address shared by multiple domains?

Tags: ip

First of all, I am helping my client to change his domain which should point to my company's hosting, but I don't know much about this type of situation.

The hosting is hosted on a server with multiple hostings. They all share the same ip address. And I need to point the domain to a particular hosting (which has a different domain pointed to it). What should I do?

Then, I use http://www.tcpiputils.com/ to look up the ip address for that particular hosting. And it displays "Found 30 domains hosted on IP address xxx.55.129.141.". Then what information do I need to point my desired domain to one of the hosting? A record, AAAA record, Nameservers????

Comment: Hosting multiple domains on a single IP address is not a matter of DNS configuration.  All the DNS entries just point to the IP.  What you need to configure is the web server itself.  The server finds out from the client what domain is requested, and sets the document root accordingly.

Comment: @Juan Tomas Does that mean my domain should still point to the ip address. However, I need to configure my web server as well? For example, if I am using Apache, I need to configure it so that all incoming requests from that domain point to a particular folder?

Comment: Correct.  The concept is a `VirtualHost`, and the documentation is [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html).  Good luck!